# Scheme: simple recursion

Tags: recursion, scheme

My recursive function multiplies the given area by 1.5 until it reaches 100,000. The output is supposed to be how many times it had to multiply by 1.5. I think I understand most of what I need to do, but I'm not sure what to put in my (if) statement.

```
(define area-multiplier
  (lambda (area)
    (if (< 100000 area)
        0         ;what do I put here?
        (+ 1 (area-multiplier (* area 1.5))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about this using an example.  In this case, the relevant examples are

```
(area-multiplier 100000)
```

and

```
(area-multiplier 100001)
```

What should these produce?

Comment: Oh, I understand. I want them to produce the amount of times area was multiplied by 1.5. Therefore, 0 was correct in that spot because it would add 0 to the total and stop recursion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine, except that if you want 100000 to return 0, then change the `<` to `<=`. :-)

Comment: I didn't even catch that. Thank you! It turned out I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how recursion worked!